# looking for a more efficient way to create new columns out of a dict in a dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to restructure my data in a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'order_id': ['A', 'B'],
                    'address': [{'city': "NY", 'latitude': 2.12, 'longitude' : 3.12,'country_code' : "US"},
                                {'city': "KL", 'latitude': 12.12, 'longitude' : 23.12,'country_code' : "MY"}]},
                   columns= ['order_id', 'address'])

df
   order_id address
0    A    {'city': 'NY', 'latitude': 2.12, 'longitude': 3.12, 'country_code': 'US'}
1    B    {'city': 'KL', 'latitude': 12.12, 'longitude': 23.12, 'country_code': 'MY'}
```

What I need is this:

```
  order_id address_city address_country_code
0        A           NY                   US
1        B           KL                   MY
```

Here is my working code:

```
new_cols = ['city', 'country_code']
for col in new_cols:
   df['address_{}'.format(col)] = \
        df['address'].map(lambda x: np.nan if pd.isnull(x) else x[col])
df.drop(['address'], axis=1)
```

How can I optimize the code to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack the cities and countries using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip) and a list comprehension.

```
cities, country_codes = zip(*[(d['city'], d['country_code']) for d in df['address']])

>>> pd.DataFrame({
    'order_id': df['order_id'].values, 
    'address_city': cities, 
    'address_country_code': country_codes})[['order_id', 'address_city', 'address_country_code']]
  order_id address_city address_country_code
0        A           NY                   US
1        B           KL                   MY
```

Comment: Sorry was the wrong edit above (deleted it). This one doesn't work for my larger dataset, I believe because of NaNs in my data: `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: You can check for nans with numpy and use a conditional list comprehension: `zip(*[(d['city'], d['country_code']) for d in df['address']] if not np.isnan(d))`. You could also pre-filter the null addresses `zip(*[(d['city'], d['country_code']) for d in df.loc[df.address.notnull(), 'address']])`.

Comment: Got `TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe'`. But this one worked: `cities, country_codes = zip(*[(d['city'], d['country_code']) for d in df['billing_address'] if not pd.isnull(d)])`

Comment: Yes, forgot about that.  You can make the first method work by forgetting about the NaN check and just ensuring that they are dict types: `zip(*[(d['city'], d['country_code']) for d in df['address']] if isinstance(d, dict)`.

Comment: but, how do I concat a df and tuples?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180064/discussion-between-alexander-and-zinyosrim).

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
In [411]: df[['order_id']].join(
                pd.DataFrame(df.address.values.tolist())[['city', 'country_code']]
                  .add_prefix('address_'))
Out[411]:
  order_id address_city address_country_code
0        A           NY                   US
1        B           KL                   MY
```

---

Details

```
In [413]: pd.DataFrame(df.address.values.tolist())
Out[413]:
  city country_code  latitude  longitude
0   NY           US      2.12       3.12
1   KL           MY     12.12      23.12
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check `concat`

```
pd.concat([df.order_id,df.address.apply(pd.Series)[['city','country_code']].add_prefix('address_')],axis=1)
```

Out[232]:

```
  order_id address_city address_country_code
0        A           NY                   US
1        B           KL                   MY
```

Comment: are you getting following warning as well ? /Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/api.py:43: RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects union = _union_indexes(indexes) /Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/api.py:77: RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects result = result.union(other)

Comment: @zinyosrim nope I did not